# JavaScriptでHTMLを書き換えたいです。

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

JavaScriptを用いてHTMLを書き換えたいです。
特定の文章から正規表現を用いて、特定の文字列を取得後、HTMLを追加する事は可能でしょうか？
UserScriptと同じくページ読み込み後に実行させます。

この様なページがあったとして

```
<a href="jump/ad/dsa/">NEWS 20200522 ほげほげほげ1</a>
<a href="jump/ad/fsd/">NEWS 20200430 ほげほげほげ2</a>
<a href="jump/ad/htr/">NEWS 20200310 ほげほげほげ3</a>
<a href="jump/ad/ahr/">NEWS 20200212 ほげほげほげ4</a>
```

> NEWS 20200522 ほげほげほげ1
>   NEWS 20200430 ほげほげほげ2
>   NEWS 20200310 ほげほげほげ3
>   NEWS 20200212 ほげほげほげ4

↓ JavaScriptを用いて以下の様に書き換えたいです。

```
<a href="jump/ad/dsa/">NEWS 20200522 ほげほげほげ1</a><a href="nojump/news/20200522/"> [JUMP]</a>
<a href="jump/ad/fsd/">NEWS 20200430 ほげほげほげ2</a><a href="nojump/news/20200430/"> [JUMP]</a>
<a href="jump/ad/htr/">NEWS 20200310 ほげほげほげ3</a><a href="nojump/news/20200310/"> [JUMP]</a>
<a href="jump/ad/ahr/">NEWS 20200212 ほげほげほげ4</a><a href="nojump/news/20200212/"> [JUMP]</a>
```

> NEWS 20200522 ほげほげほげ1 [JUMP]
>   NEWS 20200430 ほげほげほげ2 [JUMP]
>   NEWS 20200310 ほげほげほげ3 [JUMP]
>   NEWS 20200212 ほげほげほげ4 [JUMP]

初心者ながらの知識で考えてはみたのですが

```
var NEWSTITLE = ???
var NEWSID = NEWSTITLE.replace(/NEWS\s(\d+?)\s.*$/g, "$1");
jQuery("a:contains('NEWS')").after('<a href="nojump/news/' + NEWSID + '/">JUMP</a>');
```

ここが限界でした。助力頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは、jQueryを使うのであれば以下のように出来ると思います。

```js
$("a:contains('NEWS')").each(function (i) {
    var txt = $(this).text().trim();
    var id = txt.split(/\s+/)[1];
    var a = $("<a href='nojump/news/" + id + "/'>[JUMP]</a>");
    $(this).after(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="jump/ad/dsa/">NEWS 20200522 ほげほげほげ1</a>
<a href="jump/ad/fsd/">NEWS 20200430 ほげほげほげ2</a>
<a href="jump/ad/htr/">NEWS 20200310 ほげほげほげ3</a>
<a href="jump/ad/ahr/">NEWS 20200212 ほげほげほげ4</a>
```

Comment: 確かに動作しました。初歩的なことすら分からない中ご親切にありがとうございます！